# Node.js server on raspberry pi 3 not loading in web browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I am new to node.js on the raspberry pi and am trying to get my first local server up and running. I have my computer remote ssh into my pi and am using vscode to run my node.js file.

```js
console.log('test')
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end('Hello World!');
}).listen(8080);
```

When running the basic local server file, I am unable to access the page at localhost:8080. The terminal correctly displays my logged message, however, so it is running. This may have something to do with me possibly incorrectly installing node (I'm not sure if i did or need to download the Linux Binaries ARM) on my pi.

Comment: Are you trying to access the page from your computer? the `localhost` of your computer is your computer, not the raspberry pi.

Comment: oh, thank you. I am new to this stuff and i didn't understand how that worked. So would opening a tab at https://<my pi's IP>:8080 do what i want?

Comment: it should, if your port on your pi is exposed to the intranet/internet

Answer (score 0):

Your raspberry pi & node server configuration seems to be fine.

If you are trying to check from the terminal you must use `curl`

in your case it will `curl http://localhost:8080` and you will receive the server response.

If you want to check for your remote machine browser you would need to connect either using raspberry pi IP or the hostname. You can try below commands over ssh to get IP or hostname

````
hostname        // for hostname

hostname -i     // for local IP

hostname -I     // for public IP```
````